# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dest_file_name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Having issue with the code, I'm getting error with this code, was trying to make script to take a backup of a file scheduled

```
from datetime import date
import os
import shutil
import schedule

today = date.today()
date_format = today.strftime("%d_%b_%Y_")

src_file_name = "file.txt"
src_folder = "C:\\Users\\Xealtron\\Desktop\\Backup\\BackupFolder"
dest_file_name = "file.txt"
dest_folder = "C:\\Users\\Xealtron\\Desktop\\bup"


def take_backup():
    try:

    if dest_file_name != "":
        dest_file_name = src_file_name
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src_folder, src_file_name),
                     os.path.join(dest_folder, date_format + dest_file_name))

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exists,\
    please give the complete path")


schedule.every(10).second.do(take_backup())
```

Comment: add `global dest_file_name` at the top of that function

Comment: As an aside, right now you call the function once and then try to schedule its return value of `None`. I think you want to do `schedule.every(10).second.do(take_backup)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dest_file_name` is a global variable, as it is defined at the top-level of a script. When you *assign* a new value to a global variable *within a function*, you have to declare that variable to be global:

```
def take_backup():
    global dest_file_name  # Declare the variable to be global
    if dest_file_name != "":
        dest_file_name = src_file_name
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src_folder, src_file_name),
                     os.path.join(dest_folder, date_format + dest_file_name))
```